# How to download a file in asp.net without directing to another page

Tags: c#, asp.net

This code worked when it was in the PageLoad function of another page, and I just redirected to it. But When I keep this in the same page , it throws an error -

Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.

```
protected void Download(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
  //Response.Redirect("/Forms/Download.aspx?file="+sFile, false);
   string sFile = "~/Attachments"+e.CommandArgument.ToString();

   If(File.Exists(Server.MapPath(sFile)))
    {
       string Path = Server.MapPath(sFile));
       FileInfo file = new FileInfo(path);

        if (file.Exists)    
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ClearHeaders();
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" 
                                                                +file.Name);
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
            Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
            Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
            Response.End();
        }    
    }
}
```

The last time I got this error, someone suggested to add 'false' to endResponse. But dont know where to do that here.

Answer (score 0):

```
return File(document.Data, document.ContentType, document.Name);
```

This will give the user a download prompt on return.

Comment: Should this be in the Download.aspx.cs. What would the return type for that function then.

Comment: you can simply use object as a return type.

Answer (score 0):

Please try following sequence of code:

```
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" 
                                                            +file.Name);
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.Close();
        Response.End();
```

Comment: try HttpApplication.CompleteRequest instead of Response.End()